# links/tags inside a file

Tags: tags

I apologize in advance for not knowing enough even to ask the question correctly.

I'd like to implement something like the links in the help files (that you jump to using <kbd>ctl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>) in my own file, but I'm not even sure what to call them.

Specifically, I have a text file with a bunch of entries, each marked with a headword. I'd like to automatically generate a hyperlinked table of contents based on the headwords.

I know it's possible, since Bram did it in the tutorial file (unless it's written in something other than Vim?).

Thanks!

Comment: To understand how it works (and use it as a starting point for your own idea): http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/54.html